# Why I don't see Tomcat after run docker tomcat?

Tags: docker, tomcat

I am quite new with Docker. I follow this tutorial: https://stackjava.com/docker/huong-dan-cai-apache-tomcat-bang-docker-sua-port-username-password.html

My command

```
docker pull tomcat
docker run -it tomcat
docker ps -a
docker inspect -f '{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 5e55df1c76bb

docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 5e55df1c76bb

docker inspect 5e55df1c76bb

docker inspect --format="{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}"  5e55df1c76bb

172.17.0.2
```

but I access: http://172.17.0.2:8080 see nothing

[image]

```
C:\Users\donhuvy>docker inspect 5e55df1c76bb
[
    {
        "Id": "5e55df1c76bb8dff9e423b7750b62594e150bb2468b033acad18ea9f7d445229",
        "Created": "2020-10-05T16:02:40.7573065Z",
        "Path": "catalina.sh",
        "Args": [
            "run"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 987,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-10-05T16:02:41.1437801Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:f796d3d2c1954864eae249749f0a17480fb446c22053f4451e2c3514c561638b",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/5e55df1c76bb8dff9e423b7750b62594e150bb2468b033acad18ea9f7d445229/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/5e55df1c76bb8dff9e423b7750b62594e150bb2468b033acad18ea9f7d445229/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/5e55df1c76bb8dff9e423b7750b62594e150bb2468b033acad18ea9f7d445229/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/5e55df1c76bb8dff9e423b7750b62594e150bb2468b033acad18ea9f7d445229/5e55df1c76bb8dff9e423b7750b62594e150bb2468b033acad18ea9f7d445229-json.log",
        "Name": "/recursing_mirzakhani",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                29,
                125
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/73d16111a45bdfadbd3504d2ce0c252f2fd5f03d7a7f1340b35f68179d06ff52-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f4ba32e9f0e1ab529e63310679569d7dcc1e661711b9ee4318e2ee65891f994/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fce4dda91aa387a1637fcac186996c18e34f8972cc7556023a84ceed8f9547c6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f57b2ab773944fe913da9c109de5d74d21f79c5f6b00e9362247916de89a480b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1fb80e26e111dac4d0afd9cd069da39b0e4d6005f649fefc9f62786d644ef10c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/71d4caaff5263b8a146f8e512cdc94ddd5a64d0ce06aefd2806b17ba7b2bb1e1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/94bbeff68944707d4ec182874b3054e241f87f184cc73370fd2a4872cc7ee4f5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ff0f6369023d7c463b55141759b930eadbeacb60dcb2f64b27bef652dffb754c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d067db196d1894c9685f3bd71d2f5ee6e321784de6ec2ccd8f2ce0744042083/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f9bd339ee715bbed03a969664abfe5aa89f39c22cb42a69d89a9a989edd17257/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a92a068cbd132637742e14d1df96c081342ba8ab10663ef87197058b39e618e5/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/73d16111a45bdfadbd3504d2ce0c252f2fd5f03d7a7f1340b35f68179d06ff52/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/73d16111a45bdfadbd3504d2ce0c252f2fd5f03d7a7f1340b35f68179d06ff52/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/73d16111a45bdfadbd3504d2ce0c252f2fd5f03d7a7f1340b35f68179d06ff52/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "5e55df1c76bb",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": true,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": true,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/bin:/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-11",
                "JAVA_VERSION=11.0.8",
                "CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat",
                "TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR=/usr/local/tomcat/native-jni-lib",
                "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/native-jni-lib",
                "GPG_KEYS=05AB33110949707C93A279E3D3EFE6B686867BA6 07E48665A34DCAFAE522E5E6266191C37C037D42 47309207D818FFD8DCD3F83F1931D684307A10A5 541FBE7D8F78B25E055DDEE13C370389288584E7 61B832AC2F1C5A90F0F9B00A1C506407564C17A3 79F7026C690BAA50B92CD8B66A3AD3F4F22C4FED 9BA44C2621385CB966EBA586F72C284D731FABEE A27677289986DB50844682F8ACB77FC2E86E29AC A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7 DCFD35E0BF8CA7344752DE8B6FB21E8933C60243 F3A04C595DB5B6A5F1ECA43E3B7BBB100D811BBE F7DA48BB64BCB84ECBA7EE6935CD23C10D498E23",
                "TOMCAT_MAJOR=9",
                "TOMCAT_VERSION=9.0.38",
                "TOMCAT_SHA512=37117164c9ab985b4f3032deac9617cee01463f8822586a62a9c498d2720fac23a8207fcf7a76cea2fcb3c6f828ff12b7b31422316a7d92e707c3bd8d687e303"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "catalina.sh",
                "run"
            ],
            "Image": "tomcat",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/local/tomcat",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "c2b2e13e21b94eb338ce47eb6f7319f719bd1d617fef7535d81f10210408be2a",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/c2b2e13e21b9",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "f9582dfa8c2818b7f9846bf45fe3b56e671ca89efd2adab77c512d958beede7d",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "85106b65ae7140fb90ba8edcb0247f2fcf904f84cd540e6689613b5615b95bb5",
                    "EndpointID": "f9582dfa8c2818b7f9846bf45fe3b56e671ca89efd2adab77c512d958beede7d",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

C:\Users\donhuvy>
```

[image]

How to see the result of Tomcat on web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tutorial you are referring to is a bit outdated. You can run the tomcat docker container using a command like

```
docker run --rm --name tomcat-server -p 8080:8080 tomcat:latest
```

Access tomcat at http://localhost:8080

Further information is [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat). You would initially get a 404 as the `webapp` folder is empty. You can refer to [this](https://www.topzenith.com/2020/07/http-status-404-not-found-docker-tomcat-image.html) documentation which should help in getting a basic Tomcat installation running. You can then follow from step 3 of the original tutorial you are refer to.

```
docker exec -it tomcat-server /bin/bash
mv webapps webapps2
mv webapps.dist/ webapps
exit
```